# Which maven scope to use?

Tags: maven

My project needs el-api.jar for compilation.
At the same time, this library is provided by Tomcat container, when the web app gets deployed.

What should I do in order to compile the project successfully, but at the same time - to not include el-api into my WEB-INF/lib?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic usecase for the `provided` scope.

To quote the [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> **provided**
>   This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Comment: Provided:These jars will be considered only at complie time and test time
Ex: servlet.jar will be provided by deployed server, so no need to provide from our prepared War file.Scopes are quite well explained in here: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies